# Ubuntu 16.04 Black Screen with Intel GMA 3650 graphics

Tags: intel

I've installed a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 server on a system with Intel GMA 3650 integrated graphics with the Intel Desktop Board D2550MUD2 motherboard. I can get to the bootloader and see it start booting, but then the screen goes black.

I've tried everything I can find on stackoverflow and Ubuntu forms.. Adding nomodeset, i915.modeset=0, nosplash, acpi_osi=Linux, setting intel_pstate to the end of the 'linux' line in grub, setting the display size in grub, trying VGA, DVI. I've also turned off UEFI boot and any security settings. No matter what I do I get a black screen. Some made the screen go black earlier, but nothing made it better.

I know it's just the screen, as if I wait for it to fully boot and login, I can issue a shutdown or restart and it will shutdown or restart. I just can't see it.

Does anyone know specifically what I can do for the GMA3650 so I can see the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread has been sitting for a bit but, just in case you did not find an answer. I ran into the same issue with an Intel Atom with the GMA 3600 series on-board video chipset. If you can get to the unit via SSH you can try the following.

1. Edit the Grub file using a txt editor like nano or vi/vim: sudo vim /etc/default/grub
2. Add nomodeset:

   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet
       splash"
3. Save and exit the file
4. Update Grub: sudo update-grub
5. Reboot to check

Answer (score 0):

*This solution may be a unique solution for the server variant of Ubuntu only.*

Just had this issue on a AD2550R/U3S3 motherboard with Ubuntu 16.04.2 Server. Installation display works fine, post installation display no longer works after a quick text scroll (doesn't get to login.)

Intel GMA 3600 GPU had no display output and wasn't fixed my nomodeset or other GMA related fixes found here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo

The fix was found to be *blacklisting* the driver as per:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2250571

via the /etc/default/grub

Bear in mind this solution disables the driver and thus your performance will be penalized (not really an issue if you use Ubuntu Server!)